# How to collect EVS codec from pcap file

Tags: audio, pcap

I have several pcap files which captured by wireshark.

[image: I collected this data]

I collected that data from pcap file, payload data.
and saved it as file.
I tried to convert it to pcm data with this link
https://github.com/ToughmanL/EVS_CODEC

but it seems the data I collected is not EVS format.
please let me know how to get EVS codec from pcap file.

Comment: References to what a WEV and ESV data may be helpful. No other pcap tagged question references these data / file types

Comment: something mistake from the question, I mean the audio file. evs codec to pcm file.
but first I need to find way to get evs data from pcap file.

Comment: Am I correct in summarising that you wish to extract EVS encoded audio data from data acquired via Packet Capture (PCAP). After that, you then wish to convert the EVS data to PCM contained in a `.wav` file?

Comment: yes that's right. if you know, please help me, it's urgent.. if it is possible, let me know your skype id, let's meet on chat.

Comment: Then would you agree that this can be split into two questions? You are unlikely to get a good response with a compound question. Split this into 2 questions.

Comment: Since SO is based around programming questions, you should also add a language tag to each question. You should also provide a bare minimum example and some temporary data if possible

Comment: sure, thank you,. I will edit my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235411/discussion-between-fdcpp-and-rolland-costomarob).

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that Stack Overflow is for programming questions, so here is an answer based on existing / example source code. First, in your screen cap Wireshark has found a commonly used form of EVS; the 61 byte packet payload length matches the EVS spec for 24400 bps primary mode, using compact format, which means (i) no ToC header byte in the payload, and (ii) only the payload size determines the bitrate. Second, to feed that to the 3GPP decoder you have to create a file with a MIME header and format, which is needed by the 3GPP reference program.

[x86_mediatest.cpp](https://github.com/signalogic/SigSRF_SDK/blob/master/apps/mediaTest/x86_mediaTest.c) (under the mediaTest folder in the [Docker containers here](https://hub.docker.com/u/signalogic)) does this - it reads a pcap record-by-record, pulls out RTP payloads and writes them to a .cod file (coded format), including the MIME header. Running the 3GPP program on that file, with appropriate command line options then gives a PCM raw audio file you can convert to wav using sox, Audacity, Hypersignal, etc.

In x86_mediaTest.cpp, look for "if (pcap_extract) {". Also note the comment "If pcap RTP payloads are in CH (Compact Header) format, they are converted to FH (Header-Full) format by adding a ToC payload header byte". Which may explain why in your case, if you directly copied the compact header format payloads and fed them to the 3GPP decoder, it didn't work.

There is also a [mediaMin](https://github.com/signalogic/SigSRF_SDK/tree/master/apps/mediaMin) program that will take the pcap on the command line and do the whole thing, generating a .wav file. You can use that for comparison and audio quality testing vs your code.

Disclaimer: I work for the company that created the mediaTest and mediaMin tools